# How to find mobile OS name and OS version using Java-ME?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, symbian

I need to find mobile OS name and OS version programmatically: like `Symbian s40 3rd edition` or `5th edition`. How to achieve this in J2ME?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.getProperty("microedition.platform");` It will return something like  Nokia6310i/4.42.

See http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?86604-j2me-system-properties

http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/questions/properties/

I am not sure it is exactly what you need but this is what I can offer you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also detect features programatically.  Query the `microedition.platform` to see if it's a Nokia.  Then, check for the existence of APIs which distinguish the versions you are interested in.  E.g., to check whether the Location API JSR179 is present:

```
boolean hasJSR179 = false;
try {
    Class.forName("javax.microedition.location.LocationException");
    hasJSR179 = true;
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { /* no JSR 179 */ }
```